# Using the 'new' Form Wizard in django-formtools Django 1.8

Tags: python, django, wizard

New to Django and I'm trying to implement the Form Wizard (specifically SessionWizardView) from the django-formtools package, however running into a few problems setting the tags which is causing an error when rending the template - it's currently producing the following error when I extend an admin template (admin/change_form.html) to render a form

> "Reverse for 'app_list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'app_label': ''}

What's the best way to set the values for these template tags using SessionWizardView?

Comment: Please add some info. The urls.py, the templates, the forms and the Wizard subclass. I'm trying also to use the formwizard, with more info maybe someone may help us